# How to sort data frame by data if date format is not standard in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I included a photo of a part of my data frame called dfbtc1 and the columns of the dat is called created_at. Now, I would like to sort the data frame by date such that it starts with thu sept 15 00.00.... and ends at thu sept 15 23.59....
Here I include a picture of the current data frame.

[image: Date of data]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of an image, please use `dput()` function to share example data - perhaps only a few rows of a single column `created_at` to demonstrate would be helpful...

Comment: Sure!

The dput(df_new_btc1$created_at[1:10]) gives the following output: c("Thu Sep 15 23:53:28 +0000 2022", "Thu Sep 15 23:49:10 +0000 2022", 
"Thu Sep 15 23:47:31 +0000 2022", "Thu Sep 15 23:41:27 +0000 2022", 
"Thu Sep 15 23:38:03 +0000 2022", "Thu Sep 15 23:37:44 +0000 2022", 
"Thu Sep 15 23:32:56 +0000 2022", "Thu Sep 15 23:31:05 +0000 2022", 
"Thu Sep 15 23:25:33 +0000 2022", "Thu Sep 15 23:20:41 +0000 2022"
)

Comment: If you could, edit your original post and put your `dput` result there (instead of comment). Also, you can try `strptime(df_new_btc1$created_at, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")` to convert character values into POSIXlt times. Then you should be able to sort or order more easily. You can also try `parse_date_time` from `lubridate`, as well as other alternatives. Hope this is helpful.